# can't connect ssh sh: 6000: command not found

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I'm trying to connect my server
and ssh show me: `sh: 6000: command not found`
blow is ssh verbose log and my sshd_config.

```sh
[~] # ssh -v admin@myserver -P 6000
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.50.21 [192.168.50.21] port 6000.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.50.216000 as 'admin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:XTuaKA/5nJd1wol9+Ckp0or8XCx3Rd/0NGMIdT9lrro
debug1: Host '192.168.50.21' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:XTuaKA/5nJd1wol9+Ckp0or8XCx3Rd/0NGMIdT9lrro /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
admin@192.168.50.21's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.50.21 ([192.168.50.21]6000).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending command: 6000
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
sh: 6000: command not found
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2248, received 3052 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 14674.8, received 19923.2
debug1: Exit status 127
```

this is my sshd config

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.74 2006/07/19 13:07:10 dtucker Exp $                   

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See                           
# sshd_config(5) for more information.                                                   

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin                         

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with                  
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where                           
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a                      
# default value.                                                                         

#Port 22                                                                                 
#Protocol 2,1                                                                            
Protocol 2                                                                               
#AddressFamily any                                                                       
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0                                                                   
#ListenAddress ::                                                                        

# HostKey for protocol version 1                                                         
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key                                                           
# HostKeys for protocol version 2                                                        
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key                                                        
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key                                                        

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key                                    
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no

#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10
#PermitTunnel no

# no default banner path
#Banner /some/path

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

AllowUsers admin
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

I don't know why this error show here.
And I use a mac software called ssh shell it can connect to my server.
I'm pretty sure the password is right.

Comment: @jww thx, Never know this site before, I'll close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commandline doesn't do what you think it does.

```
ssh -v admin@myserver -P 6000
```

- `-v` enables some debug information
- `admin@myserver` provides the remote user and remote host
- `-P 6000` does **NOT** attempt to connect to port 6000

The command you probably intended was:

```
ssh -v admin@myserver -p 6000
```

However, it turns out that `-P` is an [undocumented argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463376/ssh-p-option-whats-it-used-for) that is accepted by ssh.

This leaves an unaccounted for argument `6000`. ssh assumes this is a command that you want to run on the remote server. It doesn't exist, which results in the error shown:

```
sh: 6000: command not found
```

Comment: NB `ssh` uses lower-case `-p` for the port option; `scp` and `sftp` use upper-case `-P`.

Comment: thx, these commands sometimes use `p`, sometimes use `P`, this is bad for remember.